# Get a list of companies with multiple share classes

Tags: r, list, sorting

I am a beginner in R, and I have a table that consists of two columns. The first column is the company name. The second one is the share class. Most of the time, companies have one class of shares. But I want get a list of companies with multiple share classes (say, two share classes).

Given this

[image]

in this case, I want to get

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
names(which(rowSums(table(df))>1))
[1] "3" "6"  # Companies 3 and 6 have more than 1 share class
```

or even

```
subset(aggregate(.~company, unique(df), length), `share class`>1)

  company share class
3       3           2
5       6           2
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(company = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L), `share class` = c("a", 
"a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```